# JLabels dont show

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

So I have a panel and depending upon users entry they are populated with an x number of jlabels. Now the problem is, when the user entered information the labels successfully populate but they do not display properly in the panel; they don't even show.

Only when I resize the frame they appear?

Comment: for better help sonner please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise everrything will be shots to the dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I did Swing programming and I am trying to remember the method which you are supposed on a container after you add components. I think it's `revalidate()`.

Answer (score 1):

usually you have to call:

```
JPanel yourPanel = new JPanel();
yourPanel.repaint();
yourPanel.validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate` marks a component as needing to be relaid out soon because the component or one of its children has been resized or become visible or invisible.  `invalidate` is called on a component automatically when children components are added/removed.

`validate` checks that a container is valid and if not, calls doLayout or invalidateTree to calculate positions and sizes of children components.  `validate` effectively  redoes the layouts if necessary, deciding on new sizes and locations of all components in the container.

After adding/removing components from a container, `validate` must be called on the parent to let the LayoutManager redo the layout.  Calling `validate` does not schedule a repaint, so you may need to call `repaint` after the `validate`.